# Where does advanced approvals do field updates

Tags: approval-process, cpq

In the normal approval process there is an approval action section which we can have field updates. But when I read through the advanced approval process I don't find a place to have this. May I know where should I place them?

Comment: Are you talking about normal salesforce approval process or anything else as you have tagged your question as cpq?

Comment: @KiranMachhewar it is the advanced approval process which cpq+ provides